# Overflow-x auto working in Chrome but need to get proper responsive width values for IE/FF support

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a web application where if, on a page, one of the widgets / web parts has too many columns, it expands the page horizontally, outside of the bounds of all of the other elements. So it would extend beyond the footer/header and make the page look as if it were cut in half vertically.

In Chrome I can set overflow-x:width auto on this specific container no problem, however in IE and FF this is a problem as a width needs to be set. `width:auto`
and `width:100%` do not work. I could use pixel values but I am trying to develop for the wide variety of screen and resolution sizes in our agency. The web app itself is already responsive it's just in this specific scenario, having too many columns does this.

Since none of those options really work, I am thinking I have to use some Javascript to get a width value in pixels.

Is there a way I can use JS to get a 'best value' or 'maximum pixel size' when the page loads/re-sizes for the container it's in so that it fits in the page without causing the body(and not this container itself)to scroll?

Example of overflow-x:auto 'working' in Chrome:

https://i.imgur.com/Wf3kB8t.png

Example of overflow-x:auto not working in IE/Firefox, I have to scroll to the right to see the rest of the columns and I'd rather it just be in a scrollable container:

https://i.imgur.com/dLAJq2v.png

Comment: Think you really have to add some code to your question and/or images. This way you just ask for opinion, which is bad.

Comment: I'm not really asking for an opinion, my thought is I'm sure I'll have to use Javascript for the solution but I'm not aware if it's possible to get a 'best value' or 'max pixels' in terms of container width to set the width to in pixels, that's what I'm asking. I'll add images to my post.

Comment: Could be you are giving overflow-x to the wrong element, but can't tell because you did not post the code. Try giving it to the parent element instead.